# Countdown timer in Unity C script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I have been working on a Unity project for sometime, I have a timer which currently counts down from around 30 minutes, however I want this to be 4 hours counting down. here is my code:

```
seconds = Mathf.CeilToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60;
        minutes = Mathf.CeilToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 60; 
    }

    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
        chestfree.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        checker = 2;
    }

    remainingTime = string.Format("{0:00} : {1:00}", minutes, seconds); 
    if (seconds != 0 && minutes != 0) {
        h.text = remainingTime.ToString ();
    } else {

        h.text = "Get";
    }
```

So you can see I have seconds and minutes in there, I tried to change the / 60 after minutes to 19 and when it ran it displayed 240 minutes which was fine, but the countdown seems to be very odd, minutes go down after around 20 seconds so I know thats not the right way to do it!

Can anyone explain to me how to add in hours or how I can make the minutes count down from 240 minutes?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not use a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) object, it can do all the math for you then. `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)`

Comment: Thanks Scott, can you explain how I use  it? Do I just replace the Math lines for each seconds and minutes and hours or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you would replace the 3 math lines with a single line `TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)` then you could use `span.Hours`, `span.Minutes` and `span.Seconds`, you also could use the [time span formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) and simplify your format to `remainingTime = span.ToString(@"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss");`

Answer (score 0):

Untested code below:

```
hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600);
minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad-hours*3600) / 60); 
seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt((gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60);



if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0) {
    chestfree.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    checker = 2;
}
//remainingTime = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",hours,minutes,seconds);
remainingTime = string.Format("{2:00} : {0:00} : {1:00}", minutes, seconds,hours); 
if (seconds != 0 && minutes != 0 && hours != 0) {
    h.text = remainingTime.ToString ();
} else {

    h.text = "Get";
}
```

I'm not sure about the construction of the remainingTime string. I would have used something like this:

```
remainingTime = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",hours,minutes,seconds);
```

EDIT:
`(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)/60` is an integer operation, that's why it did not work. By forcing float operation it should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, one thing how do I set the timer to be 3:59:59 and countdown, with your code it shows a different hour, How do I work out the hours and minutes in the Math??

Comment: If I put 3600 on the hours they show 00 on the timer. I just need them to show 4 hours and count down, I just can't figure it out

Comment: Hmm, what about using `FloorToInt` instead? `CeilToInt` strikes me as odd here. (@CliveSmith, so you get the notification.)

Comment: I am still trying to learn about timers, not sure why it is how it is and at the moment the clock is very random, for example I just tried and the timer says 1:72:59 thats 1 hour 72 minutes! All I want is the timer to count down from 4 hours and then action at the end and reset

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, it looks like the calculations are wrong for the minutes too. Hopefully the user comes back in a bit to correct them, if not I can write up an answer.

Comment: Thanks, anything you can do would be great, I have been stuck on this for 24 hours now and I feel stupid!

Comment: Any ideas Serlite? I don't know what to do to get it working!

Comment: @CliveSmith Alright, I'll just add them as comments here for now and hope the user updates their answer. The `minutes` calculation is wrong because it should only take into account minutes that aren't part of complete hours. So do the `hours` calculation first, then update the minutes line to be `minutes = Mathf.CeilToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad - hours * 60) / 60;`. That's the quickest (maybe not cleanest) way to get the count right.

Comment: @CliveSmith I just edited my answer, sorry for the mistake. I guess Time.timeSinceLevelLoad is an integer? Then it should work now

Comment: @Serlite Now I'm kind of confused, isn't it hours*3600? Because I am calculating in seconds

Comment: Oh yeah. Typo on my part, it should've gone outside of the division. =P Inside it would be *3600.

Comment: Is CeilToInt even the correct operation? For instance if we have 100 seconds left, the float operation would return '2', while the integer operation would return '1'

Comment: I'm even more confused, can you replace these three lines with the right ones to display 4 hour countdown?
seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60;
   minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 60; 
   hours = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 800;

Comment: @Kugelschreiber_Y No, that's why I suggested `FloorToInt` in an earlier comment - otherwise, even partial hours would be considered full hours (which is not how conventional timers work).

Comment: Where does the 800 come from

Comment: that was me trying to get it correct and failing. I now have this:
seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60;
   minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad - hours * 3600) / 60; 
   hours = Mathf.FloorToInt (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600;

But it shows : 0:25:30seconds

Comment: Can you please try again the updated code above, hopefully it will work. What Output-string method do you use?

Comment: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `float' to `int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Thats on this line:
seconds = (gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60;

Comment: Sorry thought both were integers, just add Mathf.FloorToInt while initializing seconds

Comment: that gives me the following when I play in Unity:
01:26:20 seconds. One Hour, 26 minutes and 20 seconds. I really need it to be 4 hours counting down, I  have been stuck on this for 3 days now, its so frustrating, any other ideas?

Comment: The calculation above is mathematically correct. Maybe a comprehensive question: gameTimer are the seconds of your Timer (in your car 4*3600 seconds) and Time.timeSinceLevelLoad are the seconds since the Timer startet (as int or float)?

Comment: well I changed me system clock forward to reset the timer on load, and when reset it shows 1 hour. I added in this and get the hours correct, but the minutes are 72...
hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 4*3600);
   minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad-hours*3600) / 60); 
   seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt((gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60);

Comment: Ok I think I have the hours working, its just the minutes showing 61 rather than max 60 minutes:
hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600*4);
   minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad-hours) / 60); 
   seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt((gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60);
Any ideas what I do with the minutes line?

Comment: minutes should max show 59! i think your hour calculation four times faster than it should, if you use gameTimer=3600; (60 min)

Comment: yes but that only shows 1 hour, how do I show 4 hours?

Comment: @CliveSmith Just initialize `gameTimer` to 3600 times the number of hours, then. So for 4 hours, use `gameTimer = 3600 * 4`. Don't modify any of the seconds/minutes/hours calculation code.

Comment: thats what I tried, after around 10 minutes the hour goes down by 1.
Here is the code:
hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600*4);
   minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad-hours) / 60); 
   seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt((gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) % 60);

Comment: @CliveSmith You should only be doing `hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600);`, not `hours = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)(gameTimer - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) / 3600*4);` - or hours will go down 4 times too fast.